# Flutter type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to write the code when register success the system navigate to home page. I success to save data to database and the response status is 200, but still doesn't navigate to home page.

**This the code register_page.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    AuthProvider authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);

    handleRegister() async {

      print('handleRegister() called');
      if (await authProvider.register(
          name: nameController.text,
          username: usernameController.text,
          email: emailController.text,
          password: passwordController.text)) {
        print('register() returned true');
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      } else {
        print('register() returned false');
      }
    }    
    Widget button(){
      return Container(
        height: 50,
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: handleRegister,
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: primaryColor,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
              )
          ),
          child: Text("Sign Up", style: primaryTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: medium
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

...
```

**This the code usermodel.dart**

```
class UserModel{
  late int id;
  late String name;
  late String email;
  late String username;
  late String profilePhotoUrl;
  late String token;

  UserModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
    required this.username,
    required this.profilePhotoUrl,
    required this.token
  });

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    username = json['username'];
    name = json['name'];
    profilePhotoUrl = json['profile_photo_url'];
    token = json['token'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){
    return{
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'username': username,
      'profile_photo_url': profilePhotoUrl,
      'token' : token
    };
  }
}
```

**This the code authservice.dart**

```
class AuthService {
  String baseUrl = "http://192.168.100.229:8000/api";

  Future<UserModel> register(
      {required String name,
      required String username,
      required String email,
      required String password}) async {
    var url = '$baseUrl/register';
    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    var body = jsonEncode({
      'name': name,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'password': password
    });

    var response =
        await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers, body: body);

    log('code ${response.statusCode} ');
    log('status : ${response.statusCode == 200? true : false}');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(data['user']);
      user.token = data['token_type'] + " " + data['access_token'];
      log("register success");
      return user;
    } else {
      log("register fail");
      throw Exception("register failed");
    }
  }
```

**This the code authprovider.dart**

```
class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late UserModel _user;

  UserModel get user => _user;

  set user(UserModel user) {
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> register(
      {required String name,
      required String username,
      required String email,
      required String password}) async {
    try {
      UserModel user = await AuthService().register(
          name: name, username: username, email: email, password: password);

      _user = user;

      log("auth provider true");
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      log("auth provider false", error: e);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**This the console log**

```
I/flutter ( 1421): handleRegister() called
I/flutter ( 1421): register() returned false
[log] response: {"meta":{"code":200,"status":"success","message":"user registered"},
"data":{"accsess_token":"36|8mP0VUWk6wvSjcNdsAUJKoDHZB4LwANtFebzkP1o",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"user":{"id":29,"name":"jian","email":"jian@gmail.com","username":"jian12","roles":"USER","email_verified_at":null,"current_team_id":null,"profile_photo_path":null,"created_at":"2023-04-26T12:06:49.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-04-26T12:06:49.000000Z","profile_photo_url":"https:\/\/ui-avatars.com\/api\/?name=j&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF"}}} 
[log] code 200 
[log] status : true
[log] register success
[log] auth provider false
      type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Even auth provider return false, the data still save in database but doesn't navigate to home page.
How to fix that problem?

Comment: The cause is in the error string. Somewhere you are trying to assign `null` to something expecting a `String`. Follow the stacktrace to find out where.

Comment: Issue in your UserModel, Send that

Comment: there is no null in form input, the data success save in the database

Comment: Send a screen shot of the error, There is a file name where is issue.

Comment: I have updated post, please check the  code user model

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. The error you posted shows that there is in fact a `null` in there somewhere, and the stacktrace will tell you exactly where. It's likely happening somewhere in the call to `AuthService().register`, but there isn't enough information in what you posted to be able to guess at more than that.

Comment: It's most likely that the null is inside the JSON response from the server, where one of the fields you are extracting in `UserModel.fromJson` doesn't exist. You need to either validate that the JSON you are receiving is valid or figure out why the server isn't sending what you are expecting to receive.

Comment: Yeah, there's no `token` field in the user data.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read `data['access_token']`, but in the JSON you receive, it's misspelled as `accsess_token`.

That means you get `null` and you try to put that into a String that you declared to be not-null.

You should probably fix the JSON coming from the backend.